# Open an URL in the Default Web Browser in WinRT

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows-runtime

The question says it all. Basically, I just want to know the alternative for this in WinRT:

```
Process.Start("http://www.google.com/");
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In WinRT, you can use `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync` to launch the default app associated with the specified URI.  For a web link, the default browser would be used.

[MSDN: Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(Uri) | launchUriAsync(Uri) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh701480)

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Windows.System.Launcher` to launch files and URL's...

- `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(Uri)` will launch a given Uri with the default application. If it's a link it will open with default web browser. You can use `file:///` scheme to open an network resource, but not resources on the local file system.
- `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(IStorageFile)` will launch the default application for the given file.

Both that methods has an optional second parameter of type `Windows.System.LauncherOptions` that customizes the launch.