# How to start a Process from a Win 8 App?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-metro

I can’t find System.Diagnostics.Process to start a new process. I guess this is on purpose. But is there a other way? Is this even possible?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334226/open-an-url-in-the-default-web-browser-in-winrt help?

Comment: no… I don’t want to open an URL/URI.

Comment: @MarcelB it is not possible to start an EXE directly from a Win 8 App...

Comment: bummer!… but I’m not giving up yet :)

Comment: hmm… looks like the Sandbox, in which the apps are running in, is more like a cage… good work MS :)

Answer (score 4):

> You can use this reference on Windows 8 Metro application : [How to Start a external Program from Metro App](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/14e2be68-ef86-4480-a3fd-6ddf7ec7d1f1).
>    All the Metro-style applications work in the highly sand boxed environment and there is no way to directly start an external application.

You can try using [Launcher class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241801.aspx)

1. [Launcher.LaunchFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701465.aspx#Y0)

   ```
   // Path to the file in the app package to launch
   string exeFile = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\App.exe";

   var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation
                           .GetFileAsync(exeFile);

   if (file != null)
   {
       // Set the option to show the picker
       var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
       options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;

       // Launch the retrieved file
       bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, options);
       if (success)
       {
          // File launched
       }
       else
       {
          // File launching failed
       }
   }
   ```
2. [Launcher.LaunchUriAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh701476)

Reference: [Can I use Windows.System.Launcher.LauncherDefaultProgram(Uri) to invoke another metro style app?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-NL/winappswithhtml5/thread/b38bb2de-2a05-4f7d-8547-48b9759d72d4)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it’s not possible to open any non-metro processes. You can open URLs or Files like *.txt, but not *.cmd or *.exe.

If there is a Custom File Association you could possibly(I haven’t try this) start a process by opening an empty file with your custom filename extension. But you can’t edit the registry to add the association from your app.
So there are no App-Only ways to do this (except not yet discovered hacks ;) ).

Comment: If you want your Windows Store app to pass certification and actually get into the Windows Store, then "hacks" are not an option anyway.

Comment: I know… I didn’t meant that serious…