# How do I call a console application from a Windows 8 application?

Tags: c#, console-application, windows-rt

I have a Windows RT Application and a console application. The console application performs certain tasks with Microsoft PowerPoint and a few other applications and it works as a standalone application. I now want to call this console application from the Windows RT application that I have.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Take a look at [Process.Start()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Process.Start() does not exist in Windows 8. Is there an equivalent to the same? 

Thanks, btw.

Comment: I guess you could also try [Launcher.LaunchFileAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701465.aspx#Y0). Also, take a look at this post, I think this is similar to the issue you're facing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563559/how-to-start-a-process-from-a-win-8-app

Comment: You can't, don't bother trying.