# How open URL in a default browser with XAML ( windows-8 Application )

Tags: c#, .net, url, windows-8

How open URL in a default browser with XAML ( windows-8 Application )

when use :

```
Process.Start("http://www.google.com/");
```

Error The type or namespace name 'Process' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Diagnostics' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12334226/1656796

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Launcher.LaunchUriAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh701476) method.

```
private async void LaunchSite(string siteAddress)
{
    try
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(siteAddress);
        var launched = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //handle the exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Error The name 'Launcher' does not exist in the current context :\

Comment: I've updated the answer with the full namespace. You need to either add `using Windows.System;` at the top of your code or type out the namespace.

Comment: i would like when user click in the button the application open the website
why can do it

Comment: Did you try the updated code? (with the fully qualified namespace `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);`)

Comment: with all namespace error else